# What are the reasons to use sys.exit() to wrap a function call?

Tags: python, anaconda, anaconda3

In several Python scripts included with Anaconda, sys.exit() is applied to a main() function. Here's an example from a script to launch jupyter notebook :

```
import re
import sys

from jupyter_core.command import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

What's the purpose of using sys.exit() as a way to wrap the call of the function main() ? According to the Python documentation sys.exit() just raises a SystemExit exception signaling an intention to exit the interpreter (https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit).

Thanks.

Comment: `Anaconda` is not a programming language. You are therefore not referring to an `anaconda script` because there is no such thing. Want you have here is a `python` script

Comment: The purpose is to pass through _exit status_. That exception carries information about whether the script's parent process should be told it succeeded or failed.

Comment: in shell (ie. `bash`) and many languages `exit(0)` means that program was finished without problem. And `exit(other_number)` it treated as error and `other_number` is used as information about this error - and later you can check this number in documentation to get more information. And if `main()` returns number with status/error then `exit(...)` can send it to shell and you can use this in shell to detect problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the next part of the documentation that you have linked:

> `sys.exit([arg])`
> Raise a SystemExit exception, signaling an intention to exit the interpreter.
> **The optional argument arg can be an integer giving the exit status.**

So the argument is used as an [exit code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) for the current process.

In the cases you mention where we have `sys.exit(main())`, the `main()` function itself returns an integer depending on how it ended which is then passed through as an exit code for `sys.exit`

Comment: The script in the question is actually called from another Python script (with subprocess.call ). So the exit status carried by the SystemExit exception can actually be used by that parent process. Thanks for the answer.